# Travelling salesman problem: Python | System crash issue

Tags: python, linear-programming

I'm solving a travelling salesman problem. I have a list of salesman who are mapped to certain set of outlets. I also have geographical coordinates of the salesmen's origin (home) and that of the outlets. I'm trying to minimise distance travelled over a period of 24 days split equally into 6 days each. Outlets must be visited depending on the frequency defined.

PFB the code. The issue I'm facing is: On Google Colab, the system just crashes unexpectedly. So I tried on my Mac and there too it seems to crash. Segmentation Fault 11.

Please help me out :)

```
from ortools.constraint_solver import routing_enums_pb2
from ortools.constraint_solver import pywrapcp
import pandas as pd
import math

# Read data from the Excel file
data = pd.read_excel('your_data_file.xlsx')

# Automatically count the number of unique salesmen
num_salesmen = len(data['Sales_Member_ID'].unique())

# List to store schedules for each salesman
member_schedules = []

# Haversine distance calculation function
def haversine(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2):
    # Radius of the Earth in kilometers
    R = 6371.0
    
    # Convert latitude and longitude from degrees to radians
    lat1 = math.radians(lat1)
    lon1 = math.radians(lon1)
    lat2 = math.radians(lat2)
    lon2 = math.radians(lon2)
    
    # Haversine formula
    dlon = lon2 - lon1
    dlat = lat2 - lat1
    a = math.sin(dlat / 2)**2 + math.cos(lat1) * math.cos(lat2) * math.sin(dlon / 2)**2
    c = 2 * math.atan2(math.sqrt(a), math.sqrt(1 - a))
    
    # Calculate the distance
    distance = R * c
    return distance

# Solve the VRP for each salesman separately
for salesman_id in range(1, num_salesmen + 1):
    # Filter data for the current salesman
    salesman_data = data[data['Sales_Member_ID'] == salesman_id]
    
    # Number of outlets for the current salesman
    num_outlets = len(salesman_data)
    
    # Create a distance matrix for the current salesman
    distance_matrix = [[0] * num_outlets for _ in range(num_outlets)]

    for i in range(num_outlets):
        for j in range(num_outlets):
            if i != j:
                distance_matrix[i][j] = haversine(
                    salesman_data['Outlet_Latitude'].iloc[i],
                    salesman_data['Outlet_Longitude'].iloc[i],
                    salesman_data['Outlet_Latitude'].iloc[j],
                    salesman_data['Outlet_Longitude'].iloc[j]
                )
    
    # Create the routing index manager
    manager = pywrapcp.RoutingIndexManager(num_outlets, 1, 0)  # 1 vehicle, depot at index 0

    # Create Routing Model
    routing = pywrapcp.RoutingModel(manager)

    # Define cost function (minimize total distance)
    def distance_callback(from_index, to_index):
        from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
        to_node = manager.IndexToNode(to_index)
        return distance_matrix[from_node][to_node]

    transit_callback_index = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(distance_callback)
    routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfAllVehicles(transit_callback_index)

    # Set 10 seconds as the time dimension for each outlet (adjust as needed)
    time_dimension = routing.GetDimensionOrDie('Time')
    for i in range(num_outlets):
        time_dimension.CumulVar(manager.NodeToIndex(i)).SetRange(0, 10 * 3600)  # 10 hours in seconds

    # Set solution strategy
    search_parameters = pywrapcp.DefaultRoutingSearchParameters()
    search_parameters.local_search_metaheuristic = (routing_enums_pb2.LocalSearchMetaheuristic.GUIDED_LOCAL_SEARCH)

    # Solve the VRP for the current salesman
    solution = routing.SolveWithParameters(search_parameters)

    # Extract the schedule for the current salesman
    if solution:
        schedule = []
        index = routing.Start(0)
        while not routing.IsEnd(index):
            node_index = manager.IndexToNode(index)
            schedule.append(salesman_data['Outlet_Name'].iloc[node_index])
            index = solution.Value(routing.NextVar(index))
        member_schedules.append({'Sales_Member_ID': salesman_id, 'Outlet_Schedule': schedule * 24})  # Repeat schedule for 24 days

# Save the member schedules to separate sheets in one Excel file
with pd.ExcelWriter('salesman_schedules.xlsx') as writer:
    for member_schedule in member_schedules:
        schedule_df = pd.DataFrame({'Outlet_Schedule': member_schedule['Outlet_Schedule']})
        schedule_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=f'Salesman_{member_schedule["Sales_Member_ID"]}', index=False)
```